# drawing a time axis - d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can someone help me draw an axis with 1 tick for each hour (6am-6pm).
    I'll later draw minute ticks - 60 ticks/hr.
    I just started learning d3 today and can't figure this out.

```
var x = d3.time.scale();    

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
         .attr('width', 1000).attr('height', 850);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom')
           .tickFormat(d3.time.format());

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'axis')
   .call(xAxis)
   .attr('transform','translate(20, 10)');
```

Comment: Have you seen [`axis.ticks()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks)? The documentation has an example that pretty much does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var x = d3.time.scale();
>
> var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
>            .attr('width', 1000).attr('height', 850);
>
> var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom')
>              .tickFormat(d3.time.format());
>              .ticks(d3.time.hours, 1)
>
> svg.append('g').attr('class', 'axis')    .call(xAxis)
>   .attr('transform','translate(20, 10)');

here is the link https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks

> .ticks(d3.time.hours),1)

is what you need..

for minutes

> .ticks(d3.time.minutes),1)